# Excel - Sum column until it reaches a cell that is not a number

Tags: excel, formula

I want to be able to use "sub sums" that sums up every number until it reaches a formula or "end of page". The range has to be dynamic, if a new line is inserted it has to be included in the range even if its inserted at the end of the range.

```
=SUM(XXX) = 20
5

5
5
5
=SUM(XXX) = 15
5
5
5
```

How can i achive this without using VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following formula in each place you want the formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,ROW()+1):INDEX(INDEX(A:A,ROW()+1):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)),IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((ISFORMULA(INDEX(A:A,ROW()+1):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))),),0)-1,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)-ROW())))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you VERRY MUCH! It works flawlessley. Im impressed that you could put together that oneliner :)

Comment: I started to add this into my excel sheet with 160 rows but on cell E128 get an error about circle reference. Do you have any clue about this?

Comment: No I do not get that, try deleting the line and reapplying the formula.  Or fill the formula from the bottom up.  It may be that the formula above is seeing that as part of its sum and kicking out the error before recalculation.